# OpenID SSO implementation in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, openid

I have a url https://custom-domain/sso/oauth2/.well-known/openid-configuration and I am bit new to this stuff.

May I know how one can use this url to implement OpenID login feature in ASP.Net application

How I can create a client id and implement it so that users can login with their credentials

Any headstart will be helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad - you are requesting a tutorial how to implement OAuth2 in an application with unknown requirements.

Comment: I tried creating an account on https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/openid-connect-discovery and there they had SSO option but with a limited set of external providers. I am aware of oauth implementation when it comes to Google Facebook or Twitter but this is the first time I am implementing a custom one @janhalasa